# SQL Server Where with 3 variables 1 is mandatory

Tags: php, sql-server

Currently have a query that needs to return from a table 'Jobs' based on customer code and the status. Basic I want to display all jobs for the customer where the job status is not 'PICKEDUP' or if it is 'PICKEDUP' the 'uploadedshipping' (date) is within the last 24 hours.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs
WHERE custcode='$custcode' AND (status!='PICKEDUP' OR  uploadedshipping > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE ()))
ORDER BY datercvd DESC, job ASC
```

This however is return all items with uploadedshipping with the last 24 hours. What am I doing wrong in the where?

Comment: You forgot to add "AND status = 'PICKEDUP'" condition next to "uploadedshipping > ..."

Comment: @Anton why would that be the case?  The or statement should return true if either 1 of those is true....

Comment: hmm... probably I did not understand the requirements correctly. So the logic should be 'all items with last 24 hours' + all with 'pickedup'? Is Status nullable?

Comment: @Anton Its all items with custcode AND status not 'PICKEDUP' or all items with custcode AND uploadedshipping within last 24 hours.  The uploaded shipping attribute is only set when status is 'PICKEDUP'

Comment: Is Status nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my answer based on Anton's suggestion.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs
WHERE custcode = '$custcode' AND (status != 'PICKEDUP' OR (uploadedshipping > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE ()) AND status = 'PICKEDUP'))
ORDER BY datercvd DESC, job ASC
```

Let me know if it worked. My bad. This is wrong

Comment: I'm am using odbc_connect and the drive throws an error on now().  Didn't think now was correct syntax for SQL Server

Comment: Don't think there needs to be status picked up again.  If uploadedshipping is set then status is 'PICKEDUP', that field gets set when status is changed to 'PICKEDUP'

Comment: Can you post a preview of your database as well as its data?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't. Working on patching broken code on a live site and don't have a local copy or admin access to the DB to make a copy.  Crappy situation